# behavior of float-point conversion to integer

Tags: c++, floating-point, type-conversion

I've a fixed-length integer class and i know how to implement the conversion from my type to native float-point and vice verse but there is special cases that i don't know what to do:

suppose signed type name is `T` and the unsigned version is `UT`, type size is `128-bit`

(1) native float-point value is greater/smaller than what `T` or `UT` can represent?

(2) value of `T` or `UT` is greater/smaller than what native float-point can represent?

Should i truncate, throw exception or set result to zero?

thank you.

Comment: I don't think this is a programming question! It depends on your domain. If the software can afford to go on by loosing precision, then you can just truncate, otherwise throw an error.

Comment: i think it would be better that you store some flag, and depending the  value  of this flag you should truncate or throw an exception.

Comment: @OzairKafray: actually the class is part of open-source fixed-length arithmetic types library i create and it can be used anywhere, that is why i did ask this question

Comment: You might find this interesting: [Comparing an Integer with a Float](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/comparing-an-integer-with-a-floating-poi/240150886#). Not necessarily directly on target for what you're doing, but related.

Comment: Have you had a look at **strtod** and **strtof** functions?  They give explicit return values in the case of these sorts of errors. Your operators should mimic what these do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question I'm not sure you fully understand floating point. Floating point representations have both magnitude and precision, but your question is only talking about magnitude. So although your integer could be within the range representable by a floating point it still may not be accurately representable as a floating point. Do you care about loss of accuracy?

My choice would be to throw an exception, but to also include methods to check beforehand whether one number is representable in the other format. Give the user of your code the choice of how they want to handle the special cases in other words.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to construct integer-float pair classes whose max & min values are compatible with each other

Comment: lets say you have a 128 bit signed integer, and its max value is (+-)2^127. If you build you floating number whose maximum value is the same value as your integer (at the cost of using more number of bits) you would not have face exceptions. For 128 bit unsigned integer part you may need bigger floating point values and you can construct another BigFloat class

Comment: when i said float-point i meant native float-point, which are already in the language. Thanks anyway.

Comment: if you plan a conversion between your own big integer class and standard floating point class, you may run into data losses.

Answer (score 0):

> float-point value is greater/smaller than what T or UT can represent?

Could be. The language standard requires floating point types to support values at least as big as 10<sup>37</sup>, or, equivalently 2<sup>122</sup>, which is close to the maximum 128-bit integer value (signed or unsigned).

> value of T or UT is greater/smaller than what float-point can represent?

Could be.

The maximum finite value of the IEEE-754 single precision floating point format is a little less than 2<sup>128</sup>, while the same for the IEEE-754 double precision format is a little less than 2<sup>1024</sup>.

These answers ultimately depend on your platform.

> Should i truncate, throw exception or set result to zero?

It's up to you.